# Magmi: how to define 'product in websites' when importing products?

Tags: magento, magmi

Can someone please advise how to define to which websites a product should be added when importing products with Magmi? In the Magento backend this can be changed by clicking on the 'Websites' tab when editing a product. This opens a tab called 'Product in Websites'.

Already tried to add the websites to the 'stores', 'websites' or '_product_websites' columns but that doesn't seem to do the job. When importing a new item it always enabled all websites by default, when updating existing products it doesn't modify this configuration.

The only reference I could find in the Magmi documentation doesn't seem to explain this:
http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Magmi_Behaviour_-_store_column

Using Magmi v0.7.18 and Magento v1.8.1.0.
The following page mentions that the websites fiels is now OBSOLETE when importing data with Magmi, not sure if this is the problem: http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Import_new_products

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"websites" is obsolete, you can only use "store" to define a product in particular store view and that will work .

Comment: Thanks, using 'store' does the job for new entries.
I can also add an existing product to other websites using the 'store' field, but I can't remove a product from specific websites using this field. Is this intended behaviour?

Comment: You need to use [Product Deleter](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Product_Deleter) Plugin to delete products using Magmi .

Please use column name magmi:delete with the value of 1 for products you want to be removed from Magento.

Comment: How can i remove all products from the selected website in multistore?